# TypeScript is there some elegant way to reflect child class type in the parent class?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I has a base class

```js
class Animal {
  public abstract clone(): Animal
}
```

and some derived classes

```js
class Dog extends Aniaml {
  public clone(): Dog {
    return clone(this)
  }
}
class Cat extends Aniaml {
  public clone(): Cat {
    return clone(this)
  }
}
```

Since the `clone()` implementations in the derived classes is identical each other. DRY priciple tells me that the code is less elegent.

So the version 2:

```js
class Animal {
  public clone(): Animal {
    return clone(this)
  }
}
class Dog extends Aniaml {}
class Cat extends Aniaml {}
```

In this way, it's more elegant. But there is one thing bother me which, see below:

```js
const dog = new Dog()
const clonedDog = dog.clone() // typeof clonedDog is 'Animal'
const clonedDog = dog.clone() as Animal // typeof clonedDog is 'Dog' but I dont want type assertion here
```

So, the question is: Is there the elegant way to auto infer `clone()` 's concrete return type in the derived classes?

I already had one solution but I dont think it's elegant :(

```js
// still less elegant
class Animal<T> {
  public clone(): <T> {
    return clone(this)
  }
}
class Dog extends Aniaml<Dog> {}
class Cat extends Aniaml<Cat> {}
```

THANKS for the any help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `this` type. It is the type of the current implementation.

```
class Animal {
    clone(): this {
        return clone(this)
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {}

const dog = new Dog()
const clonedDog = dog.clone() // Dog
```

Comment: Thanks! May I ask for a link to the documentation of `this` type?   I don't even know `this` can be a type, I only knew `typeof this`...

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types